# using linear congruential generator to obfuscate row ID?

Tags: random, database-design, uniqueidentifier

let say we have a system which stores e-commerce orders as one row in a database and a sequential incrementing int is used as primary key.

now we would like to expose the order ID to the customer but by using the database row ID as order ID a customer would be able to to figure out that order volumes.

its been suggested to use **Lehmer random number generator** to obfuscate the ID. The upper limit for the system is set to 2^31 -1 which is a recommended prime number and used in many libraries. since the used prime and multiplier for many libraries is already [provided it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use) it good idea to use one of these since the number been verified and tested as prime numbers.

but using these number does not offer any obfuscation since it very easy to regenerate the result for a incremental sequence.

How are order IDs, customer IDs usually generated by system without exposing the database sequence.

UUID is not an option, the upper limit is **2^31 -1**

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to convert sequential integer into something which is not decipherable. Simple solution is to use AES cipher in RNG mode. Something along the line of https://github.com/swenson/aesrng

Answer (score 0):

You could stack any number of transforms to make reversal more difficult, but you'll never make it impossible.

A trivial way to keep a large secret as part of the algorithm is to make a substitution table for each byte in the word.

```
x = table0[x & 255]
  | (table1[(x >> 8) & 255] << 8)
  | (table2[(x >> 16) & 255] << 16)
  | (table3[(x >> 24) & 127] << 24);
```

Where each table is a shuffle of 0..255 (except the last table which is 0..127 for you because you only want 31 bits).

Then use that in conjunction with other transforms, like `x = x ^ (x >> 11)` and `x = x * 1103515245 % 2147483648`.

As long as every individual step produces a unique number, then the full chain will also produce a unique number.